# javascript arguments are messed up when passed to NPAPI plugin function

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, npapi

I am using a simple NPAPI example from https://github.com/mikma/npsimple.

When I try to pass arguments from javascript to the NPAPI invoke function, the
parameters recieved by the NPAPI function are garbage, though argument count is
passed correctly. The following is the definition of the function in which I am trying to print the "args" array after converting them to char*:

```
invoke(NPObject* obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard for someone to tell what you are doing wrong without being able to see the code that's not working.

Comment: I am just trying the run the example at https://github.com/mikma/npsimple. I have just changed the javascript function in test.html to pass few parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really hard to tell what you're trying to do based on what you have given us. Specifically, as smorgan requested, we need to know how you are trying to convert the args array to char*.

You are aware of how the [NPVariant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPVariant) works? If it's a string, the NPVariant type will be NPVariantType_String and you will need to use both the UTF8Characters member of the [NPString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPString) struct (which in turn is part of the NPVariant union) and the UTF8Length member, since the string may or may not be null terminated.

Also, keep in mind that depending on what you put in, it may or may not be valid to make your NPVariant a char*. If that helps, great; if it doesn't, please post the contents of the function in which you are trying to handle the input as well as the specific javascript calls that you are making.  You haven't given us enough to work with to give you more than guesses as to what problem you may be having.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian, I got it working. The problem was that the string was not null terminated.

Comment: Excelent; since that was one of the thigns I suggested you check, could you mark this as the answer please? =] Thanks